# issue with pickadate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery plugin where the functionality of the pickadate is not working as expected

```
var picker = $('##gameDate3').pickadate({}).pickadate('picker');

if(gameDateJsAway != 0) {
     picker.set('select', gameDateJsAway);
}
```

the above works, but when i have to use it again in 2nd instance, i renamed it as picker2 from picker

but it always throw error on the `undefined set`

if i keep the name same for the both input fields where i am trying to load existing date, it works for one only and other one does not work,

trying to figure out how can i use it from 2nd input field.

any clues or any idea

explained the issue above